# Filtrar Usuário AD - PowerShell/CSV

Tags: windows, csv, powershell, active-directory, ad

Caros colegas,

Preciso ler um arquivo de CSV e filtrar os usuários dentro do AD com as informações contidas no CSV. Preciso comparar o campo CSV com o UserPrincipalName dentro do AD.

Meu script está assim:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory    
$Users = "C:\Script\leiaute.csv"    
Import-CSV $Users -Header UserPrincipalName | Foreach-Object {        
Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like '$_'" -SearchBase 'OU=BHZ,OU=MG,DC=elv,DC=intranet' | % {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.’UserPrincipalName’ -Enabled $false}
```

Não me retorna nenhuma mensagem de erro, mas não realiza a tarefa desejada.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reescrevi trecho do código

```
$Base = 'OU=BHZ,OU=MG,DC=elv,DC=intranet'
Import-CSV $Users -Header 'UserPrincipalName' |
    Foreach-Object -Process {
linha 1 Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like '$PSItem'" -SearchBase $Base |
linha 2     Foreach-Object -Process {
linha 3         Set-ADUser -Identity $PSItem.'UserPrincipalName' -Enabled $false
linha 4     }
    }
```

2. Você não colocou uma linha de exemplo do seu CSV. Então, certifique-se que o comando `Get-ADUser` retorna algo. Remova as linhas 2, 3 e 4, e remova o caractere de redirecionamento `|` no final da linha 1. Execute e verifique que uma coleção é retornada.
3. Para o comando `Set-ADUser`, o parâmetro `Identity` pode ser:

- `Distinguished Name` ==> CN=JimSmith,OU=europe,CN=users,DC=corp,DC=SS64,DC=com
- `GUID (objectGUID)` ==> 599c3d2e-f72d-4d20-8a88-030d99495f20
- `Security Identifier (objectSid)` ==> S-1-5-21-3165297888-301567370-576410423-1103
- `Security Accounts Manager (SAM) Account Name (sAMAccountName)` ==> AnnualReports

Fonte: [Guia de referência da SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/set-aduser.html)

4. O campo LDAP `UserPrincipalName`, vulgo UPN, é baseado no padrão RFC822 da Internet. Geralmente um endereço eletrônico, vulgo e-mail. O seu arquivo CSV deve estar correto. Aí está provavelmente o equívoco, ao associar `UserPrincipalName` com `Identity`. Quando existe um comando em powershell com o sufixo `Get` ele costuma retornar uma coleção de itens a qual pode ser redirecionada para o comando `Set`, sem a necessidade de explicitar o campo `Identity`.
5. Então, remova as linhas 2 e 4, e substitua a linha 3 por `Set-ADUser -Enabled $false`.